# My friend is in prison but he was able to get a stimulus check. How to cash it?

Tags: united-states, banking, irs, stimulus

My friend is in prison, however he was able to get a stimulus check from the IRS when they were allowed to. I tried to deposit his check into my account after he signed it, but my bank rejected the check after they stamped it, and they said that they where going to send it back to the IRS.

Inwhich they did. So my friend had to get it re issued. I have been trying to help him get the check cash, but I can't find a place that will cash it. So then we did the power of attorney form, and still I can't find anyone that will cash that check for him even after I present the POA.

What can I do? Is there an online banking I can set up to deposit the check. Keep in mind he is in prison so he don't have an ID or driver license that can up loaded into a bank system... Again what can I do?

Comment: Sounds like a scam. After you try to cash the check and you transfer cash to him, he will disappear, and then the bank will ask you to reimburse for the failed cheque.

Comment: Does your friend have a bank account?

Answer (score 6):

IRS checks cannot be transferred via endorsement, it has to be deposited to the account with his name on it. FINRA has issued numerous warnings about abuse related to tax refund ([example](https://www.fincen.gov/resources/advisories/fincen-advisory-fin-2013-a001)), and banks are very conservative when it comes to that.

What you're describing is a very established pattern of abuse, so I doubt you'd be able to cash that check in any way but depositing it to the payee's account.

How to open a bank account while incarcerated is a different question and I don't have a good answer for that. A criminal attorney may have some insights from experience.

Comment: Web searching "open bank account while incarcerated" finds multiple answers, though I can't vouch for the accuracy of any of them. I would point out that many incarcerated people already have bank accounts, though the poorest are most likely to be unbanked. I also second the advice that, unless this is someone you know In Real Life rather than only remotely, odds of scam are high.